# Regular expression for only allow numbers and must end with '#' sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want a regular expression that validate a string that allow only numbers and this string must end with a numeral symbol `#`.

Like:

```
353645#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using:

```
/^[0-9]+#$/
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 18):

Use $ to mean at the end of the string. Try this:

```
/^[0-9]+#$/
```

Further explanation:

```
^      Start of string
[0-9]  Only characters in 0-9
+      At least one
#      Literal #
$      End of string
```

Comment: but this is little problem in syntax and i omit $ sign and working fine...

Comment: beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
/^\d+#$/
```

Answer (score 0):

use `\d*#$` pattern. `$` means end of line